# get data from my model to my controller (Ember.js)

Tags: ember.js

Thank you in advance. I have a model and a controller. What I am trying is to access the model data from my controller and be able to play with from my controller. When init: function is fetch, on my console i get (null).Thank you again

```
//========model==========\\

App.RequestDashboardRoute = App.AuthRoute.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('request');
    }
});



//========controller==========\\
App.RequestDashboardController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    init: function(){
        console.log("model");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log("model");` is only going to log you a string `"model"`

Also, the model is not set in the controller until after `setupController` is called in the `route` (`RequestDashboardRoute` in your case)

`init` happens before `setupController`, to be sure you controller not only has a model before trying to access it but also to execute your logic again if it changes, you can add an observer, and run your logic there

```
App.RequestDashboardController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    modelChanged: function(){
       var model = this.get('model');
       // your model is ready
    }.observes('model')
});
```